# Output/Generate a set of points from individual equations - Python, JS, Matlab

Tags: javascript, python, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I began with a set of coordinates, which I then approximated a function to represent them (Fourier series). The function produced is a sum of sin and cos waves:

`0.3sin(2x) + 1.7(sin5x) + 1.8(sin43x)...`

I would like to take this new function that I generated and produce a new set of coordinates. How can I generate points for every [INTEGER X Value] say from 0-400?

Note: I have 2 complex (2D) functions.

> GOAL: Take a function --> Generate Points from this function for every whole integer.

Comment: When you say "*generate points*", are you meaning something more than this?  `X = 0:400;  fh = @(x) 0.3*sin(2*x) + 1.7*sin(5*x) + 1.8*sin(43*x);  Y = fh(X);`

Comment: you have the function right. like y = mx +c. and you have your x values. in my case ranging from 0 to 400. how can i find each value of y for these correspoonding x values and put them in a list.

Comment: Also, can you clarify why you have 4 language tags?  Which are you asking for?

Comment: (1,3) , (2, 4) , (3,5) .... etc.

Comment: these are the languages that i can use. Its part of a much bigger project, and these are easiest to work with at the moment.

Comment: Doesn't the Matlab code in the above comment do that?  If you want a 401 by 2 array of them, then `P = [X(:) Y(:)]` gives that.

Comment: oh, i didn't see that. Thanks! :)

Comment: What is the **interpolation** tag for?

Comment: When using your code, i get a 802x1 array. how can i get a 401x2

Comment: Alrighty i got it to work, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses a [function handle](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html) and `(:)` to force a column vector (`(:).'` forces a row vector).

The code simply uses the given equation (summing sines and cosines) to calculate a corresponding *y* coordinate for each given *x* coordinate.

```
% MATLAB R2018b
X = 0:400;                                                % x = 0, 1, 2, ..., 400                         
fh = @(x) 0.3*sin(2*x) + 1.7*sin(5*x) + 1.8*sin(43*x);           
Y = fh(X);

P = [X(:) Y(:)];
```

Note that `size(P)` returns **401 x 2**. You'll see `Y` takes on whatever size `X` is, which is a row vector. `X` can be declared as as column vector with `X = (0:400).'` using `.'` which performs a [transpose](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/transpose.html).

Recommend taking a look at MATLAB's [documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/), specifically the [Getting Started](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html) and [Language Fundamentals](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/language-fundamentals.html).

Relevant MATLAB functions:  [`sin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sin.html), [`cos`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.cos.html).

Answer (score 1):

Matlab Code

```
X = 0:400; 
fh = @(x) 0.3*sin(2*x) + 1.7*sin(5*x) + 1.8*sin(43*x); 
Y = fh(X);

P = [X, Y]
```